# loading different page using webView: decidePolicyForNavigationAction: request: frame: decisionListener: method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, webkit

Hii All,

I want to load a new page when following method is called....I am using the following code..

```
(void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id )listener
{
  [[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:someRequest];
}
```

but this method is called multiple times and my application crashes if i use [listener use] instead of loadRequest it works fine but launches the url clicked . but i want to load some other url how is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You should simply add `[listener ignore]` method call.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id )listener
{
    [listener ignore];
    [[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:someRequest];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called multiple times as you say, so you have to pay attention to this:
`[actionInformation valueForKey: @"WebActionNavigationTypeKey"]`

That value should be one of the `WebNavigationType` enum:
`WebNavigationTypeLinkClicked,

   WebNavigationTypeFormSubmitted,

   WebNavigationTypeBackForward,

   WebNavigationTypeReload,

   WebNavigationTypeFormResubmitted,

   WebNavigationTypeOther`

You will get `WebNavigationTypeLinkClicked` first as a result of a link clicked, and here you can decide whether to load the page clicked or something else.
Immediately after you get `WebNavigationTypeOther` which is the page load, and you can ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in this method it is mandatory to return a value.
You're supposed to decide if you accept or not this url.
So if the WebView is going to a page you don't want, 
you should return ignore.

And have the webView go to your other url: `[myWebView setMainFrameURL:otherUrlStr]`

Thanks